# Interpreting silhouette coefficeint for clara function in R

Tags: r, clustering, clara

I am trying to do clustering on a distance matrix which contains numeric data. But I am not sure how to decide upon the number of clusters or value k for clara function in R. But after running it with some random number of clusters, I ran silhouette function on it and summary gives me like this:

Cluster sizes and average silhouette widths:

```
           7            3            4            5            7            4 
 0.222273330 -0.001592881  0.117937463  0.121326365  0.137911639  0.161932689 
Individual silhouette widths:
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.10410  0.08961  0.12500  0.14140  0.19840  0.30580
```

This is the result for value of k=6. If I change it to say 5 or 4, I obtain silhouette for each cluster and also mean value. How do I decide upon the number of clusters? Do I need to plot like mean silhouette vs k? How do we do something like this in a large dataset with around million observations?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of these two things :

1. Use `fviz_nbclust()` function like this

```r
        fviz_nbclust(data, clara, method = "silhouette", 
             k.max = yourMaxValue)+theme_classic()
```

2. You could construct a graph by accessing silhouette width info in clara object.

```r
        # If clara.res is the object resulting from using clara.
        clara.res$silinfo
```

Hope this helps.